# Spark Session null pointer while processing json from kafka

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to process a json message from kafka.When I loop through the RDDs in the stream and try to use the SparkSession to read the json string, I see a null pointer exception. Can some one see what is wrong here :

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
  .builder().master("local[*]")
              .appName("ABC")
              .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
                  .getOrCreate();
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext(),Durations.seconds(2)));

        // Kafka params code here.....not shown

            JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> istream1 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    jssc,
                    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic1), kafkaParams)
                );


istream1.foreachRDD(rdd ->{ 
                rdd.foreach(consumerRecord ->{

                    Dataset<Row> rawData = spark.read().json(consumerRecord.value());
                  rawData.createOrReplaceTempView("sample");
                  Dataset<Row> resultsDF = spark.sql("SELECT alert_id, date from sample");
                  resultsDF.show();
                });
            });
```

I see that I am not able to use the spark session or the context that is part of that session in the foreachRDD section (get a null pointer).

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:112)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:110)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.(DataFrameReader.scala:535)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read(SparkSession.scala:595)
>         at com.ibm.sifs.evidence.SpoofingEvidence.lambda$1(SpoofingEvidence.java:99)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:350)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:350)
>         at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.foreach(KafkaRDD.scala:193)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$27.apply(RDD.scala:875)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$27.apply(RDD.scala:875)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>         ... 3 more